# Inject javascript to mock data

Tags: javascript, mocking, code-injection, sinon

Is there a way to import an existing file and inject javascript into the head/body?

I want to use sinon to fake a server but not for unit tests. Currently I need to access an API that only runs privately on my work servers. When I am home I would like to mock this data, without altering the original code.

So my idea was to import the index file and use sinon to fake a server response. Something along the lines of:

```
<link rel="import" href="index.html">

<script>
   var s = document.createElement("script");
   s.type = "text/javascript";
   s.src = "sinon.js";
   $("head").append(s);

   var xhr = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();
   <!-- etc. -->
</script>
```

Obviously there is clear semantic problems with the above example, this is just a gist of what I am trying to get at. Does anyone know if this is possible?